# Geometric Algebra: No other point groups besides $H_p$ and $C_p$ in two dimensions

Tags: symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups, geometric-algebras

I have been reading the paper "[Point Groups and Space Groups in Geometric Algebra](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241362632_Point_Groups_and_Space_Groups_in_Geometric_Algebra)" by David Hestenes as part of my introduction seminar to GA. On page 5 the remark is made, that to prove that $C_p$ and $H_p$ are the only point groups in 2D, one would need to prove the following: Consider the possibility of a group generated by three distinct vectors a, b, c in the same plane. If they are to be generators of a symmetry group, then each pair of them must be related by a dicyclic condition like ($(ab)^p= −1$). It can be proved, then that one of the vectors can be generated from the other two, so two vectors suﬃce to generate any symmetry group in two dimensions.

Conceptually this proof makes a lot of sense to me, since the dicyclic condition implies that a rotation of 180° can be made with only two vectors, therefore creating any vector along its path in both directions, meaning any vector at all in two dimensions. But trying to prove this in geometric algebra, I always found myself relying on linear algebra and my understanding of basis to make this rather basic proof. And it made me question my understanding of the rest of the paper, since it is never really defined which operation is even being used.

My idea to solve this with GA would be to use (ab) to define a rotation from a point x as it was done above in the paper and from there try to show that with a precise rotation, a general c can always be found. But I am unsure how the condition of c having to be related to the other vectors with the dicyclic condition would come into play.

Could someone please explain how this would be done? And I apologize for the rather trivial question.

Comment: I don't think this is trivial at all. Hestenes has a bad habit of handwaving things like this. I'm still working out the details, but this is the outline of how I think you can argue this: (1) We are specifically working with *finite* point groups. (2) Every finite point group has a unique "doubled" group of unit versors. (3) A unit versor is a product of unit vectors; a finite versor group is necessarily generated by a finite number of elements, which all can be expressed as products of a finite number of unit vectors.

Comment: (4) If we allow ourselves 1 vector $a$, then that is the only possible generator; but $a^2 = 1$ so we have $2C_2$. (5) If we have 2 (nonparallel) vectors $a, b$, then finiteness allows us to argue that there is some $p$ such that $(ab)^p = -1$; then we argue that the only relevant possible generators are $\{ab\}$ or $\{ab, b\}$, so we get $2C_p$ or $2H_p$, and then of course we know all $p$ are obtainable. (6) For three vectors, use [Cartan–Dieudonné](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Dieudonn%C3%A9_theorem) to argue them down to one or two vectors.

Comment: (7) By finiteness, this means we can always collapse $n$ vectors down to 1 or 2 vectors.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Thank you for your reply! I was wondering about (4), wouldn't $2C_2$ require a dicyclic condition aswell or is it given? And the idea of (6) would work for any c, or is the given dicyclic relation between all (a,b,c) necessary?

Comment: For (4): The group generated by $180^\circ$ rotation ($C_2$) and the group generated by one reflection are isomorphic; both are groups of order 2. For (6): Any three vectors work; Cartan-Dieudonne says that every 2D isometry preserving a point is a composition of at most two reflections preserving the same point, and this pulls back to the Clifford algebra and says that every product of vectors can be written as a product of at most two vectors. Then because a product of three vectors is odd, it can't be two vectors so it is just one vector.